# Mapbox: I want to use the Locationengine to get the current location of the user but it gets me an error

Tags: java, android, geolocation, mapbox

I get the following errors:

> Error:(81, 39) error: cannot access LostApiClient
> class file for com.mapzen.android.lost.api.LostApiClient not found
>
> Error:(82, 39) error: cannot access LocationListener
> class file for com.mapzen.android.lost.api.LocationListener not found

What can i do? I tried all i found on the www but nothing worked.

Comment: if you want to use the Lost api client, you need add the dependency in your build.gradle.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you! Now i have the problem that after i added the mapbox navigation sdk, the app label change to "Mapbox Navigation SDK for Android".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for this error: I hadn't added the dependencies for the Mapbox services sdk and the Mapbox telemetry sdk.

If you have this problem, just add these lines to the build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:2.2.10@aar'
```